# Tooltip overflow Issue in slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, tooltip

I'm working on tooltip within the slider, everything is working fine now, but when tooltip display its show behind the slider, I have tried to fix it using z-index but its not working. You can check demo here   tooltip is in first slider at bottom gray buttons.

Comment: Please show us some code, what you have tried so far.

Comment: I have added the code, please check

Comment: its because the `overflow:hidden` property given in parent divs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you set last child tooltip position right 0 and left auto to solved your problem like

```
.tooltip-effect-1:last-child .tooltip-content1{
left:auto;
right:0px;
```

}

Live **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mansukh_Khandhar/ndvawocu/1/)**

Comment: Thank you for the solution, Just one more issue, you see arrow at bottom of tooltip is there a any way to make them in center of button not tooltip and also it would be great if you give me solution to make it top on all divs and banner.